# Term for listing all possble integers that add up to a specific total

Tags: terminology

Pretty simple question, much like we use 'factorise' to describe finding the factors of a number, is there a term for finding all the (integer) numbers that can be added up in any combination to the same total?

For example, the number 3 would yield something like:

```
1 + 1 + 1 = 3
1 + 2 = 3
```

or 4 would yield:

```
1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 4
1 + 1 + 2 = 4
2 + 2 = 4
1 + 3 = 4
```

Is there a term for that?  Please excuse my not being particularly au fait with mathematical terms.

Comment: You are interested in the [**partitions**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of a number, in this case $4$. Usually one counts plain $4$ by itself also. That gives $5$ partitions of $4$.

Comment: Thanks, that's all I needed.

Comment: @You are welcome.